# website for iPhone - Javascript support?

Tags: iphone, web

I designed a small page for iPhone users. 
I used some javascript functions for it and everything works in my iPhones safari browser, but problem is - most of visitors don't use safari. At least it doesn't show up in user agent.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A334
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
```

I'm not sure what kind of browser are they using. Does it support javascript? 
So far it seems that not because most of that traffic doesn't visit page 2 of website.

Answer (score 0):

Those users are using Safari. AppleWebKit **is** Safari.

[image]

Comment: AppleWebKit/525.18.1
The WebKit engine build number.

Comment: AppleWebKit/534.46. The WebKit engine build number on my iOS5 device, checked just this second. Source: an actual iPhone. The string varies from OS revision to OS revision, and probably a little if they're ina  UIWebView.